# TensorFlow: Specify number of Ops run in parallel

Tags: tensorflow

As I understand, TF invokes multiple operators in parallel as long as they are independent. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40008117/582967))

And the parallelism can be controlled by `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` if operators ar e running on CPU ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41233635/582967)). However these parameters does not affect GPU operators at all. How can I control parallelism of GPU? (for example, run operators serially although there are independent operators)

EDIT:

```
a=tf.random_normal([N,N])
b=tf.random_normal([N,N])
c=tf.random_normal([N,N])
d=tf.random_normal([N,N])

x=tf.matmul(a,b)
y=tf.matmul(c,d)
z=tf.matmul(x,y)
```

Comment: GPU only runs one compute op at a time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481453/tensorflow-device-contexts-streams-and-context-switching

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Then sess.run(z) should take 3x than sess.run(x), right? However, in my experiment, it only takes 2x.

Comment: The first call is extra long because of initializations

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Is there any way to measure the time taken only in matmul?

Comment: added the way to measure in answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to profile execution that avoids common pitfalls:

```
# Turn off graph-rewriting optimizations
config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))

# throw error if explicit device placement can't be satisfied
config.allow_soft_placement = False

N = 8192
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    input1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N,N]))
    input2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N,N]))
    result = tf.matmul(input1, input2)
    result_no_output = result.op # to avoid transferring data back to Python
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

# load values into GPU
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# pre-warming
sess.run(result_no_output)

num_ops = N**3 + N**2*(N-1)  # N^3 muls, N^2 (N-1) adds
elapsed = []
for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()

    sess.run(result_no_output)
    elapsed.append(time.time()-start)

print("%d x %d matmul, %.2f elapsed, %.2f G ops/sec"%(N, N, min(elapsed), num_ops/min(elapsed)/10**9))
```

On TitanX pascal this shows 9.5 T ops/sec which is close to theoretical max os 11 T ops/sec theoretical maximum

```
8192 x 8192 matmul, 0.12 elapsed, 9527.10 G ops/sec
```